# Reverse strings in a nested list without slicing or reversed

Tags: python, string, list

In python if my list is

```
TheTextImage = [["111000"],["222999"]]
```

How would one loop through this list creating a new one of

```
NewTextImage = [["000111"],["999222"]]
```

Can use `[:]` but not `[::-1]`, and cannot use `reverse()`

Comment: Searching for a way to change the [::-1] in NewTextImage += TheTextImage[i][::-1], but have the same effects.

Comment: If you can't use the builtin tools for this, you have to write them yourself. You could do this just by looping `for ch in orig_string:` and adding each `ch` to the start of a `new_string` instead of to the end. (If you want it to be more efficient, build a list, or, better, a `collections.deque` and `''.join` it, but your teacher probably isn't expecting that from you.)

Comment: Thank you! How could I add 'ch' to the start of the string rather than the end?

Comment: Just do `new_string = ch + new_string`.

Answer (score 1):

You may not use `[::-1]` but you can multiply each range index by -1.

```
t = [["111000"],["222999"]]


def rev(x):
    return "".join(x[(i+1)*-1] for i in range(len(x)))

>>> [[rev(x) for x in z] for z in t]
[['000111'], ['999222']]
```

---

If you may use the `step` arg in `range`, can do AChampions suggestion:

```
def rev(x):
    return ''.join(x[i-1] for i in range(0, -len(x), -1))
```

Comment: If you are going to use `range()` - why not just use a `step` of `-1`, e.g. `''.join(x[i-1] for i in range(len(x), 0, -1))`

Comment: Hmm, not sure. You have just written, albeit in a more complicated way, `''.join(x[i-1] for i in range(0, -len(x), -1))`

Comment: Yes, probably! But isn't `"".join(x[(i+1)*-1] for i in range(len(x)))` the same logic to `''.join(x[i-1] for i in range(0, -len(x), -1))` - as in they both result in `''.join(x[-1], x[-2], x[-3], ...)`.

Comment: @AChampion well I don't know, still don't think op can do this :) added to the ans just in case.  cheers !

Answer (score 1):

You know how to copy a sequence to another sequence one by one, right?

```
new_string = ''
for ch in old_string:
    new_string = new_string + ch
```

If you want to copy the sequence in reverse, just add the new values onto the left instead of onto the right:

```
new_string = ''
for ch in old_string:
    new_string = ch + new_string
```

That's really the only trick you need.

---

Now, this isn't super-efficient, because string concatenation takes quadratic time. You could solve this by using a `collections.deque` (which you can append to the left of in constant time) and then calling `''.join` at the end. But I doubt your teacher is expecting that from you. Just do it the simple way.

---

Of course you have to loop over `TextImage` applying this to every string in every sublist in the list. That's probably what they're expecting you to use `[:]` for. But that's easy; it's just looping over lists.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use any standard functionality such as `reversed` or `[::-1]`, you can use `collections.deque` and `deque.appendleft` in a loop. Then use a list comprehension to apply the logic to multiple items.

```
from collections import deque

L = [["111000"], ["222999"]]

def reverser(x):
    out = deque()
    for i in x:
        out.appendleft(i)
    return ''.join(out)

res = [[reverser(x[0])] for x in L]

print(res)

[['000111'], ['999222']]
```

Note you *could* use a list, but appending to the beginning of a list is inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce(lambda x,y: y+x, string)` to reverse a string

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> TheTextImage = [["111000"],["222999"]]
>>> [[reduce(lambda x,y: y+x, b) for b in a] for a in TheTextImage]
[['000111'], ['999222']]
```